# Simulation not rendering

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation

i was making an blast for a clip animation, but the explosion in not working, besides that the explosion in not visible in the render mode .

This is the image of the render mode

[image]

This is the Solid

[image]

Comment: Which engine are you using?

Comment: eevee engine is what i am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the shader node setup is not correct. You can use this node setup[image: Node Setup] for the smoke domain.. I think you will get the desired result. You have to tweak with some variables in the node setup.